# move constructor when multiple arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments

I have a first constructor something like this

```
X::X(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2, const std::vector<int>& v3) : _v1(v1), _v2(v2), _v3(v3){
} // _v1 , _v2 and _v3 are members
```

for this behaviour I should also implement the move constructor versions

```
X::X(std::vector<int>&&, std::vector<int>&&, std::vector<int>&&);
```

but it is possible to have mix types of arguments of const lvalue reference and rvalue reference like this one

```
X::X(const std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&&, const std::vector<int>&);
```

is the best practice to implement all the possible constructors i.e 2^3 ?

Comment: Any constructor that doesn't take a `X&&` as its only parameter is not move constructor, it's just another regular constructor. Generally if you want to optimize this type of constructor, you should use templates and perfect forwarding.

Comment: Your second example isn't a [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), although I get what you mean. A possibility would be to use "universal references" and sfinae to constrain the types (something along [these lines](http://ideone.com/VBFqPW)), but I find this a bit obfuscated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it's a constructor we are talking about here, it's reasonably efficient to just take the arguments by value and move them:

```
X::X(std::vector<int> v1, std::vector<int> v2, std::vector<int> v3)
    : _v1(std::move(v1)), _v2(std::move(v2)), _v3(std::move(v3)) {}
```

This costs up to one extra move per vector, depending on the actual argument. But moves are cheap, and you don't have to write 8 separate constructors or some unreadable SFINAE mess.

Note that considerations are quite different if you would be doing an *assignment*. Copy construction + move assignment can be considerably less efficient than simple copy assignment, because the latter may be able to reuse the resources held by the assigned-to object. When you are constructing a fresh object, this factor doesn't come into play because there's no resource to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to pass vector by value, you may take *forwarding reference*:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
X::X(T1&& v1, T2&& v2, T3&& v3) :
    _v1(std::forward<T1>(v1)),
    _v2(std::forward<T2>(v2)),
    _v3(std::forward<T3>(v3))
{}
```

**Edit**:

As state in comment, the downside is that it accepts too much argument types. In most case, you got an error from vector constructor, but for example one vector constructor take an `int`, so `X(42, std::vector<int>{42}, v3)` would works (with `v1` a vector with 42 elements `0` and `v2` a vector of 1 elements `42`) which may be unexpected.

Restriction may be added with SFINAE, but syntax is verbose.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, T.C.'s remark is why you might want to use sfinae, but as T.C.'s stated earlier (and as you can see in [this example](http://ideone.com/VBFqPW)), it makes the code ugly.